# Json and arrays, how to

Tags: arrays, json

Hi all I have a question regarding json and how to write them correctly.
What I want to do is this (conceptually)

```
{
  "attrs": {
     "0": [
         "key": "key1",
         "value": "value1"
     ],
     "1": [],
     "n".....
   }
}
```

Edit:
The question is, how do i write it in a correct json format.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You can ask uncle Google for JSON syntax.

Comment: The only syntax error I see here is that your list elements aren't turned into objects - so `{"key": "key1"}` instead of `"key": "key1"`